# Can I install ROS1 kinetic and ROS2 crystal on same pc?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have projects on ROS Kinetic and I want to run ROS2 side by side. Is it possible to add ROS2?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64-bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322987/can-i-install-ros1-kinetic-and-ros2-crystal-on-same-pc?/) by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can I install ROS1 kinetic and ROS2 crystal on same pc? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64-bit.

The short answer would be (for your stated configuration): no, as Kinetic is not supported on Ubuntu Bionic (only on Xenial (16.04), see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)). The ROS buildfarm does not build any Kinetic packages for Bionic because of that.

The longer answer would be: *maybe*.

It might be possible to build Kinetic from source, *but* there will probably be significant incompatibilities to overcome, such as those with Qt (4 vs 5), Ogre and potentially Boost.

---

An alternative to building Kinetic from source could be to use a Docker (or Singularity) image of Kinetic (such as `ros:kinetic` or `osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop(-full)`).

Technically, that would not be an answer to your question, as it wouldn't be exactly running on the same PC / OS, so depending on your requirements / use-cases it wouldn't actually help you.

---

A second alternative could be to install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial and build ROS Crystal from source next to that. REP-2000 lists Xenial as a Tier 2 platform ([here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#crystal-clemmys-december-2018-december-2019)) and apart from some of the RQT plugins, Crystal should still compile on Xenial last I heard.

> I have projects on ROS Kinetic [..] and I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64-bit.

Btw: this confuses me, as Kinetic cannot be installed on Bionic. Are you already using containers?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2019-05-12**:
Actually, I have singularity image on my pc, but i can't install anything to it. So that's why I was looking for other options. And as you mentioned singularity image is not my answer. Btw Thanks for your clear justification.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-12**:
If you run the Singularity image as `--writable` or convert it into a `--sandbox` you could install anything you like.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-05-13**:
When installing Crystal on Xenial, the RQT plugins that fail can be compiled with an gcc 5